# Convert rendered HTML 5 display (visible and invisible) to image when using HTML 5 canvas

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas, converters, draw2d-js

Is there source code (or a browser plugin) to convert the contents of an HTML 5 web page to an image file?  This would not just include the visible contents, but the hidden contents as well (assuming there were scroll bars in the page).  If there isn't, any advice on how to approach this particular functionality would be appreciated, and I can look into it.

I found this...

[html to jpg with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7380041/html-to-jpg-with-c-sharp)

However...

I think they just had text in the page, so it doesn't have any dynamic images on the page.  My page specifically uses the HTML 5 canvas functionality to draw images.  So that must be part of the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be able to do it using javascript with this technique:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-save-drawing-as-an-image/

Make sure to take note of the following caveat however:

**Note:** The `toDataURL()` method requires that any images drawn onto the canvas are hosted on a web server with the same domain as the code executing it.  If this condition is not met, a `SECURITY_ERR` exception is thrown.

**EDIT:** You may also want to check out these related questions:

[Save HTML5 canvas contents, including dragged-upon images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127263/save-html5-canvas-contents-including-dragged-upon-images)

[How to save a HTML5 Canvas as Image on a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198131/how-to-save-a-html5-canvas-as-image-on-a-server)

Comment: document.getElementById('canvasId').toDataURL() gives this error when on localhost: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: In Mozilla Firefox, I get more detail than when I'm in Google Chrome: Use of getAttributeNode() is deprecated. Use getAttribute() instead.  .. in addition to the .toDataURL() is not a function

Comment: And the 3rd link is a repeat of the 1st link.

Comment: When I use a standard "canvas" HTML tag, this works.  I just happen to be using the draw2d.js (Draw2D Touch) library, which wraps around Raphael.js.  So I need to figure out how to reference the dynamically created canvas tag inside the div tag, they require.  I'll mark this as the answer, and will post a new question.

Comment: draw2d.js builds an SVG tag, as a child of the DIV tag, not a canvas.  So you need to put the canvas tag in the page in addition.  This worked, but now I need to figure out how to download the image.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433806/convert-embedded-svg-to-png-in-place